# Run python method in virtualenv from crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, virtualenv, ubuntu-20.04

I am currently struggling with how to run a method from a python file in a virtual environment via crontab.

I have a directory that looks as follows: `/home/ubuntu/project` has the file `file.py`
and the folder `venv` in it. In `file.py` there is a `method()` that I want to execute regularly via crontab, using the python and dependencies of the virtual environment.

I have already figured out that I need to use the python from inside the virtual environment, so instead of

`python3`

I use

`/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/python3`.

Now, I have also found answers to the question how to run a method from the command line, namely via

`python3 -c 'import foo; print foo.hello()'`.

I have tried to combine the two, but unfortunately

`/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/python3 -c 'import /home/ubuntu/project/file; print(file.method())'`

is invalid syntax. Also

`/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/python3 -c 'from /home/ubuntu/project/ import file; print(file.method())'`

only results in errors. On the other hand,

`/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/python3 -c 'import file; print(file.method())'`

results in file not being found.

How do I do this properly?

Thank you very much for considering this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `import` is not a file name. The simplest workaround is probably to `cd` into the directory, then run the script with the virtual environment's Python interpreter.

```
42 17 * * * cd project && ./venv/bin/python3 -c 'import file; file.method()'
```

from the `crontab` of the user whose home directory is `/home/ubuntu`.

More generally, the directory you want to import from needs to be on your `PYTHONPATH`,so you could equivalently set that instead of `cd` into the directory. A third alternative is to make the code in `file.py` into an installable module, and install it in the virtual environment. For a one-off, this may be an unnecessary chore, but it is definitely the most robust and sustainable solution.